# Monitor Internet SMTP Queue For Exchange 2003 with Nagios

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, nagios

Is there a way I can monitor the number of emails in the Internet SMTP Connector queue on Exchange 2003 using Nagios that are in a retry state?

Ideally, I would like to monitor ones that are in Retry and have Greater than X delivery failures.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already seen this page, but in case you haven't, there is some interesting information towards the bottom of the page under "ExchangeCommands.cfg Definitions".

Looks like it may be exactly what you are looking for.

http://nagioswiki.com/wiki/index.php/Nagios_Checks_for_Exchange_Server_200x#ExchangeCommands.cfg_Definitions

Comment: I don't see anything specific to messages in queue.  I see messages submitted (to queue), messages sent, and messages delivered.  I don't use Nagios, but if it's configurable (again, I don't know), it sounds like you'd have to come up with some kluged up algorithm to account for all three of those stats to arrive at messages still in queue.